# Add completely seperate models in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

I am somehow new to Python (my experience is mainly in .net), I created 2 sample websites from tutorials using Django and I got the results that I was expecting.

Now I want to create a more complicated website with some functionality that are not available in the Django admin, I am looking for the best practice of doing that, how can I create new pages/models to manage these functionality in the admin area?

My other question is, are there any tutorials for creating my own cruds in oython without even using Django? and is this a good approach with heavily custom applications?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The Django admin area basically provides you a fast and easy interface for your database so that you can do CRUD operations. It also provides some functions like actions to perform some operations on records and make changes. But if you want a lot of customization, then django admin is not best place for it. I have already fallen for this but after some hacky hacks for customizing django admin, it was a lot of mess and things were not going pretty well.

Solution:
As Django is based on MTV (Model Template View) framework, you will have to make Views of your Apps which would render some kind of data (django queryset or JSON etc) to the template. You can write your own template and customize everything the way you want. You can use the power of Django template Language as well. You can also use frontend Javascript frameworks for User Interface (like I have used KnockoutJS for making dynamic tables and binding fields etc.) . 
You may watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTNA0MtZwso%E2%80%8E) to get an idea of some Django beginner stuff

As far as your second question is concerned, well if you ask me, Django is going pretty well and has a HUGE community plus DjangoCon (Django Conferences , search Youtube). I am building a large scale highly customized application on it and it too good. But as for alternatives, go to [this link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) and compare for yourself and after some research you would notice that Django is leading the pack. Best of Luck and welcome to Python community:)